# Magento save method not working with Customer Model Object

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, model, ce-1.9.2.4, save

**I have used below code to update the custom column in `customer_entity` table, but the values are not updating in database.**

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
                    $customer->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
                    $customer->setLoginActive(0);

                    $customer->save();
```

It seems to be the `save()` is Failing. I have checked by Clearing the `var/cache` folder too.

Comment: What you is you custom attribute of customer???
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$customer->setCustomAttribute('887475748');
try {
    $customer->save();
    print('Saved: '.$customer->getStripeCustomerId());
} catch (Exception $e) {
   Mage::throwException($e->getMessage());
}

Comment: I have login_active custom column in table, I am doing this from admin controller.

Comment: You can do this code in controller action. First create customer object and then set custom value and save it.

Comment: Yeah, I am using this in my custom controller action only Dhrumin, I am doing this for admin customer edit page.

Comment: So it's not working????  please share your controller code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I fixed by created Customer attribute with same name and now i can able to save the attribute.